# Function for finding GCD of two numbers

Tags: java

The below code gives `-1` output for `25,15` I can't figure out why. please help

```
public static int getGreatestCommonDivisor(int first, int second){

        if(first<10 || second<10){
            return -1;
        }

        else{
            int remaining = first %second;

            if(remaining != 0){
                return getGreatestCommonDivisor(second , remaining);
            }
            else{
                return second;
            }
        }



    }
```

Comment: Whats the logic behind if statement at the very beginning. Most of the time either first or second will surely be < 10 and at that time -1 will be returned. Thats the problem I guess

Comment: GCD(25, 15) -> GCD(15, 10) -> GCD(10, 5) -> -1

Comment: Did any of the answers solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to replicate the euclidian algorithm, all you need to do is remove the if statement at the start of your code:

```
public static int getGreatestCommonDivisor(int first, int second){
  int remaining = first %second;
  if(remaining != 0){
      return getGreatestCommonDivisor(second , remaining);
  }
  else{
      return second;
  }
}
```

Input:

```
System.out.println(getGreatestCommonDivisor(25,15));
```

Output:

```
5
```

As other people have mentioned, the specific reason that you are getting `-1` with your input is because of the original if statement:

`gcd(25,15) -> remaining = 25 % 15 = 10 -> gcd(15,10) = 5 -> gcd(10,5) -> 5 < 10 -> outputs -1`

Comment: how to make sure the numbers entered are positive then?

Comment: What do you need to be outputted if a value is not positive?

Answer (score 0):

Because `25%15` is `10`, `15%10` is `5` and `5` less than `10`.

Answer (score 0):

A sample outlook onto the recursion tree for the code given will be like

```
                             gcd(25, 15)
                              /
                             /
                           gcd(15, 10)
                           /
                          /
                         gcd(10, 5) - here we have second < 10, so -1 will be returned and thats the problem.
```

**Fix** : Fix can be, you can get rid of the if statement and keep the remaining code there itself.

```java
public static int getGreatestCommonDivisor(int first, int second){

            int remaining = first %second;

            if(remaining != 0)
                return getGreatestCommonDivisor(second , remaining);
           return second;
    }
```